# GDM2000 or CASSINI to WGS84

Tags: coordinate-system, geolocation, malaysia

[image: pic1] [image: pic2]

This is a Malaysia map and there is only two GDM2000 or Cassini.
I have no idea those label stands for what,
GDM2000(U, T)
Cassini(U, B).

https://dominoc925-pages.appspot.com/webapp/gdm2000cassini/default.html
This is the only converter website I found, and there is a tutorial how to use this website
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fuH682HEm14
but I dont have the any D:M:S for the Latitude and Longitude

Any idea?

Comment: Any approximate idea where in Malaysia this is supposed to be?

Comment: Hi @TomazicM is somewhere in Pekan Gurney, Perak, Malaysia.
[link] (https://www.google.com/maps/dir///@4.236525,100.7920294,1758m/data=!3m1!1e3)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you do not have any software and need to get the conversion done. The method shown below is using [QGIS 3.x](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html):

You have 2 sets of points:

**U** stands for **Utara** (North)

**T** stands for **Timor** (East)

**B** stands for **Barat** West.

**Point A:**

Coordinates in GDM 2000
U -69151.591
T -2069.687

Coordinates in CASSINI
U 64303.524
B 2070.778

**Point B:**

Coordinates in GDM 2000
U -68148.386
T -2785.609
Coordinates in CASSINI
U 65306.729
B 2786.700

Just create a text file (I called it in my case coordinates.txt) and add the coordinates either in Cassini or GDM2000, they must be the same.

Add the content as follow:

```
Name, Easting, Northing
Point A, -69151.591, -2069.687
Point B, -68148.386, -2785.609
```

**OR**

```
Name, Easting, Northing
Point A, 2070.778, 64303.524
Point B, 2786.700, 65306.729
```

Save your file.

[image]

Download QGIS, install it.

1. Use the add comma delimited data.
2. Choose the delimited Text Tab if it is not selected
3. Open the file.

Your dialog will look like this, but most importantly you need to select the coordinate system:

[image]

Type GDM2000 then select Perak Grid:

[image]

Click on the add button:

[image]

I had issues with the coordinates above as the points were in the sea. I tried with GDM2000 Perak grid (EPSG:3384), GDM2000 peninsula (EPSG:3375) and GDM2000 (EPSG:4742). They all positioned the points on the sea or other places.

I then took the second set of data (Cassini) and saved the file name as coordinates2.txt . Made sure to change the West value to negative Easting as below:

```
Name, Easting, Northing
Point A, -2070.778, 64303.524
Point B, -2786.700, 65306.729
```

I loaded the file as per the steps above then set up the CRS to GDM2000 Perak grid (EPSG:3384) and managed to get the right position of the points:

[image]

To get the coordinates in WGS84 use the "Add X/Y fields to layer", choose the layer you want to retrieve the coordinates from and **make sure** you set the CRS to EPSG:4326 . Results are in Decimal Degree

[image]

The results will be included in the layer attribute table:

[image]